# "Confused" vs. "bewildered"

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning

Is there any major difference in the meanings of *bewildered/bewildering* and *confused/confusing*? How about the context in which they can be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definitions of the two are as follows:

**[Confuse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confuse):**

> 1 *archaic*: to bring to ruin
>
> 2
>     a: to make embarrassed : abash
>     b: to disturb in mind or purpose : throw off
>
> 3
>    a: to make indistinct : blur
>    b: to mix indiscriminately : jumble
>    c: to fail to differentiate from an often similar or related other

**[Bewilder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bewilder):**

> 1: to cause to lose one's bearings
>   2: to perplex or confuse especially by a complexity, variety, or multitude of objects or considerations

Additionally, they are listed as synonyms, so I would say it is safe to use them interchangeably where their meanings overlap. Just make sure it's a case where they do mean the same.

One example where they aren't interchangeable:

> I confused you with your sister.

means I couldn't tell the difference, or thought one was the other.

> I bewildered you with your sister.

means I used your sister to cause you confusion. Granted, the first example *could* mean that, but wouldn't be understood in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim says, if you *confuse X with Y*, you're mistakenly thinking *X* is *Y* and/or that *Y* is *X*. But in practice, people usually say *"I [mis]took you for someone else"*, rather than *"I confused you with someone else"*. You normally hear that "misclassification" sense in constructions like *"Don't confuse [my good idea] with [someone else's bad idea]"* where there's an element of *your thinking is sloppy / unfocussed / confused.*

For most other contexts, the two words are effectively synonyms, but consider the [usage history](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20confused,I%20am%20bewildered&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

If that's not enough to convince you that *confused* is probably the better choice, consider [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20confused,I%27m%20bewildered&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

...which clearly shows that in "conversational" contexts, *confused* is overwhelmingly the preferred term.

Comment: While *mistake* can be used, I believe it is primarily used for people. You could confuse *confused* with *bewildered*, but I doubt you would *mistake* it.

Comment: @Jim: Shome mishtake, surely? [28K hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+mistook+it+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books for *"I mistook **it** for"*, and only [20K](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+mistook+him+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for *"I mistook **him** for"* suggests if there's any people/objects distinction involved at all, it's not very marked.

Comment: perhaps sum up *him*, *her*, *you*, and *them*; I imagine that would be more than *it*.

Comment: Thanks very much for the charts. One question, I didn't fully understand why you said "shows that in **conversational** contexts". Probably I'm mistaken, but isn't Google ngram viewer a tool which shows the count of selected n-grams found in the **books** digitized by Google? So is there any way to show only the conversational/colloquial usage that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @narengi: It's not necessarily true for every single citation, but I think it stands to reason far more instances in the second chart will be *reported speech*, since we're much more likely to *say* the contraction **I'm** than we are to write it.